# Add Value to Column TShellListview

Tags: delphi, lazarus

I have a TShellListView in Lazarus with some Pictures in it. I also made 2 column where I want to store some data About the Picture. But I don't know how to insert the data into the columns I made (Column_1 and Column_2).

Code:

```
ShelLListView1.Column[1].Visible:=false;
 ShelLListView1.Column[2].Visible:=false;

 ShellListView1.Columns.Add;
 ShellListView1.Column[ShellListView1.ColumnCount - 1].Caption:='Column_1';
 ShellListView1.Columns.Add;
 ShellListView1.Column[ShellListView1.ColumnCount - 1].Caption:='Column_2';


 ShelLListView1.Column[0].AutoSize:=true;
 ShellListView1.Root:=folderPath;
```

Image About the TShellListView:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though making a subclass of the [**TShellListView**](http://wiki.freepascal.org/TShellListView) class would be better, what you need in any case is adding subitems to this list view:

```
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  ...
  for I := 0 to ShellListView1.Items.Count - 1 do
  begin
    ShellListView1.Items[I].SubItems.Add('Column 1, Item: ' + IntToStr(I));
    ShellListView1.Items[I].SubItems.Add('Column 2, Item: ' + IntToStr(I));
  end;
end;
```